# Inner Join with 2 separate queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I like to join to sets of data.

Not sure why the following is not working:

```
    (Select  LocID,  ParamID,  alertNumExceed, upperAlarm,  lowerAlarm,  alertOn,  EntryUserID,  ParamOrder 
     from data_LocParams )  dl 
     inner join 
    (SELECT LocId 
    from map_Sites ms
    inner join map_WaterSystems mw on mw.SiteId = ms.SiteId
    inner join map_Locations ml on mw.SysID = ml.SysID
    where ms.SiteId = 344 )  mq
    on dl.LocID = mq.LocId
```

I get the following error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'dl'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near 'mq'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't selected anything

```
SELECT dl.LocID,  ParamID,  alertNumExceed, upperAlarm,  lowerAlarm,  alertOn,  EntryUserID,  ParamOrder  
FROM
    (Select  LocID,  ParamID,  alertNumExceed, upperAlarm,  lowerAlarm,  alertOn,  EntryUserID,  ParamOrder 
     From data_LocParams )  dl 
     inner join 
    (SELECT LocId 
    from map_Sites ms
    inner join map_WaterSystems mw on mw.SiteId = ms.SiteId
    inner join map_Locations ml on mw.SysID = ml.SysID
    where ms.SiteId = 344 )  mq
    on dl.LocID = mq.LocId
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I eventually figured that out. Can you help me with the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554051/join-tables-from-2-datasets

Comment: If an answer  solved your question consider to accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that map_Locations has column named LocId, query can be simplified to

```
Select  dl.LocID,  dl.ParamID,  dl.alertNumExceed, dl.upperAlarm,  dl.lowerAlarm,  dl.alertOn,  dl.EntryUserID,  dl.ParamOrder 
from data_LocParams dl 
inner join map_Locations ml on dl.LocId = ml.DocId
inner join map_WaterSystems mw on mw.SysID = ml.SysID
inner join map_Sites ms on mw.SiteId = ms.SiteId
WHERE ms.SiteId = 344
```

or

```
Select  dl.LocID,  dl.ParamID,  dl.alertNumExceed, dl.upperAlarm,  dl.lowerAlarm,  dl.alertOn,  dl.EntryUserID,  dl.ParamOrder 
from map_Sites ms
inner join map_WaterSystems mw on mw.SiteId = ms.SiteId
inner join map_Locations ml on mw.SysID = ml.SysID
inner join from data_LocParams on dl.LocID = mq.LocId   
on dl.LocID = mq.LocId
```