# Join tables from 2 datasets

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have 2 data sets:

1)

```
    SELECT LocId 
    from map_Sites ms
    inner join map_WaterSystems mw on mw.SiteId = ms.SiteId
    inner join map_Locations ml on mw.SysID = ml.SysID
    where ms.SiteId = 344 and LocId <> 9604
```

The result of this data set is:

```
LocId 

9605
9606
```

Here is the second data set:

```
    select dl.LocId, dl.ParamID,  dl.alertNumExceed, dl.upperAlarm,  dl.lowerAlarm,  dl.alertOn,  dl.EntryUserID,  dl.ParamOrder 
    from data_LocParams dl where LocId = 9604
```

The result of this dataset is

```
LocId   ParamID alertNumExceed  upperAlarm  lowerAlarm  alertOn EntryUserID ParamOrder
9604    187 NULL            NULL            NULL            0   NULL            NULL
9604    3057    NULL            NULL            NULL            0   NULL            NULL
9604    3138    NULL            NULL            NULL            0   NULL            NULL
```

The final result I am going for is something like this:

```
LocId   ParamID alertNumExceed  upperAlarm  lowerAlarm  alertOn EntryUserID ParamOrder
9605    187 NULL            NULL            NULL            0   NULL            NULL
9605    3057    NULL            NULL            NULL            0   NULL            NULL
9605    3138    NULL            NULL            NULL            0   NULL            NULL
9606    187 NULL            NULL            NULL            0   NULL            NULL
9606    3057    NULL            NULL            NULL            0   NULL            NULL
9606    3138    NULL            NULL            NULL            0   NULL            NULL
```

Notice how for each LocId it repeats basedon the ParamID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH ResultSet1 AS (
  SELECT LocId 
    from map_Sites ms
    inner join map_WaterSystems mw on mw.SiteId = ms.SiteId
    inner join map_Locations ml on mw.SysID = ml.SysID
    where ms.SiteId = 344 and LocId <> 9604
), ResultSet2 AS (
select dl.ParamID,  dl.alertNumExceed, dl.upperAlarm,  dl.lowerAlarm,  dl.alertOn,  dl.EntryUserID,  dl.ParamOrder 
    from data_LocParams dl where LocId = 9604
)
  select
    ResultSet1.LocId, ResultSet2.*
  from ResultSet1
  cross join ResultSet2
```

---

In answer to Nate’s comment, you can INSERT using WITH:

```
WITH ResultSet1 AS (
  SELECT LocId 
    from map_Sites ms
    inner join map_WaterSystems mw on mw.SiteId = ms.SiteId
    inner join map_Locations ml on mw.SysID = ml.SysID
    where ms.SiteId = 344 and LocId <> 9604
), ResultSet2 AS (
select dl.ParamID,  dl.alertNumExceed, dl.upperAlarm,  dl.lowerAlarm,  dl.alertOn,  dl.EntryUserID,  dl.ParamOrder 
    from data_LocParams dl where LocId = 9604
)
  insert into yourTable
  select
    ResultSet1.LocId, ResultSet2.*
  from ResultSet1
  cross join ResultSet2
```

Or you can write this without WITH:

```
insert into yourTable
select
  ResultSet1.LocId, ResultSet2.*
  from (
      SELECT LocId 
        from map_Sites ms
        inner join map_WaterSystems mw on mw.SiteId = ms.SiteId
        inner join map_Locations ml on mw.SysID = ml.SysID
        where ms.SiteId = 344 and LocId <> 9604
    ) as ResultSet1
  cross join (
    select dl.ParamID,  dl.alertNumExceed, dl.upperAlarm,  dl.lowerAlarm,  dl.alertOn,  dl.EntryUserID,  dl.ParamOrder 
        from data_LocParams dl where LocId = 9604
) as ResultSet2
```

Comment: Thank you Steve. I need to insert this information into a table based on the result. How do I do that with this query. I have not worked with  with WITH keyword before

Comment: See my updated answer, where I could respond in a way that’s readable and formatted.